# To prevent expiring session variables in submit page, should I assign session variable to viewstate variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a session variable which is used to store a datatable (which changes depending on how the user wishes to add / remove items (data items in the datatable).

At the last page of the whole web application, I have a submit page to allow the user to submit the selected items in the datatable.

Because I think session variables may expire if the page is left open too long, and to prevent errors arising from expired variables, at the page_load function's !IsPostBack I assigned the session variable to a viewstate variable (so the data will be stored in the page's viewstate and not expire).

`if(!IsPostBack){  ViewState["myDataTable"] = Session["myDataTable"]}`

1) Is this the standard practice and are there any implications / errors when assigning a session variable to a viewstate?

2) After calling `ViewState["myDataTable"] = Session["myDataTable"]`, is it ok to do `Session["myDataTable"] = null` ?

Comment: Use `Profile` instead of `Session`.

Comment: How about just checking if your session variable is not null on postback, to prevent any errors on an expired session?

Comment: @Jonny that's what I thought of too. But what if we want it to be more user friendly and do not want the user to have to key in the data again, what do you suggest?

Comment: Have a look at this... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/your-session-has-timed-out.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the kind and size of data you have there.

It is key to remember that you need to treat anything you send to the client as compromised data. Another way to put it, if you'd be ok with an user having available a form that allows them to input every single bit of that data, only then it is ok.

All said, the viewstate is normally signed, but [history as proven](http://eglasius.blogspot.dk/2010/09/aspnet-padding-oracle-how-it-relates-to.html) is a good idea to follow that general security advice.

As for the size, you need to keep an eye on the amount of data being exchanged on each request.

Last about clearing that session value afterwards, asp.net mvc does similar for what it calls TempData. The scenario for its use: pass some data from one page to the next on non post scenarios + and when you don't want it in the query string.

Comment: if the size of the data gets too large, is it a good idea to be storing the data in a file on the server (and reading it back whenever user wants to load the data to page)

Comment: This depends a lot on the characteristics of your environment. Assuming it is a single web server, it is definitely a good way to avoid hitting the database if you're concerned about the hit. Note that cache like @peer suggested is also an option, but you need to watch out for high memory use if you have a lot of concurrent users doing something like this and it's also not ideal for very long term scenarios (where you'd see app domain recycles).

Comment: Also think if the data needs to be that large i.e. if for part of the data you just need to keep some id, instead of all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. but viewstate tends to slow the page loading due to extra overhead. If your dataset is small it is ok, but if its bigger then look for other alternatives.

How ever I will recommend not to go with this method[security problem,slow etc.], instead device a way so that session dosent expire if any page is open?? how?? use jquery/ajax to maintain a connection with server at regular interval.

If you want to go some further implement sql session. It will be the best.

Hope these info help you.